# How do I select three tables from a blog including author, post and views and show in php mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

The table I am trying to connect for the third selection is the viewcount which is connected to the 'prints' table by prints.print_id = totalview.name

So the selection here works but adding the third table doesn't work. What is wrong with my query?
WORKS!

```
$q = "SELECT artists.artist_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, middle_name, last_name) AS artist, print_name, price, description, print_id, image_name FROM artists, prints WHERE artists.artist_id = prints.artist_id ORDER BY artists.last_name ASC, prints.print_id ASC";
```

ERROR!

```
$q = "SELECT artists.artist_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, middle_name, last_name) AS artist, print_name, price, description, print_id, image_name, totalview.totalvisit AS totalvisit FROM artists, prints WHERE artists.artist_id = prints.artist_id, LEFT JOIN totalview ON totalview.print = prints.print_id ORDER BY artists.last_name ASC, prints.print_id ASC";
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

To show in a table as such:

```
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    // Display each record:
    echo "\t<tr>
        <td align=\"left\"><a href=\"browse_prints.php?aid={$row['artist_id']}\">{$row['artist']}</a></td>
        <td align=\"left\"><a href=\"view_print.php?pid={$row['print_id']}&name={$row['image_name']}\">{$row['print_name']}</a></td>
        <td align=\"left\">{$row['description']}</td>
        <td align=\"left\">{$row['description']}</td>
        <td align=\"right\">\${$row['price']}</td>
    </tr>\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left join clause in the wrong position  .. you can't add the left join clause after the where

and don't mixup esplicit and implicit join  use ever explicit
and  last (hope) you have also a wrong comma after the where condition

```
$q = "SELECT 
        artists.artist_id
        , CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, middle_name, last_name) AS artist
        , print_name
        , price
        , description
        , print_id
        , image_name
        , totalview.totalvisit AS totalvisit 
    FROM artists
    INNER JOIN  prints ON rtists.artist_id = prints.artist_id
    LEFT JOIN totalview ON totalview.print = prints.print_id 
    ORDER BY artists.last_name ASC, prints.print_id ASC";
```

Comment: It works, but says I can't accept until 4 minutes. I usually just break the rules and officially accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is structured incorrectly:

```
FROM artists, prints 
WHERE artists.artist_id = prints.artist_id, 
LEFT JOIN totalview ON
```

should be

```
FROM artists, prints 
LEFT JOIN totalview
```